# Azure Websites Deployment - Cannot find user- ExtendedCode 09004

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a simple AspNetCore web application to Azure Websites using the following process:

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs.html

I keep getting the error message:

"ErrorEntity": {
        "Code": "NotFound",
        "Message": "Cannot find user.",
        "ExtendedCode": "09004",
        "MessageTemplate": "Cannot find user.",
        "Parameters": [],
        "InnerErrors": null
      }

I have tried this from a new project and existing project and both give the same error.

Googling for the issue turns up the following:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7743aca4-1a88-4ef5-ab74-98992f2bbf22/cannot-find-user-error-when-creating-new-app-service-plan?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

However I haven't been able to get a solution so far.

Anyone else had this issue or managed to find an answer?

Thanks

Comment: Same issue here I think. A colleague doesn't have the same issue so might just be some accounts... not sure. Have raised azure support ticket but had to raise it under "subscription issues" rather than "technical" as I don't have a proper support plan on my MSDN account.

Comment: I have a Pay-As-You-Go account, I can open an Azure Support Ticket too if you think it might help? Where did you open the ticket?

Comment: https://portal.azure.com/?whr=live.com#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft stated it was an intermittent issue. There is a workaround they provided but it's not longer an issue for me so I can't test it. Might help someone so I've provided it below anyway for the sake of completeness. If like me you no longer have an issue I suggest this question is closed.

1. Go to portal.azure.com -> Browse -> App Services -> (open any web app) -> Settings -> Deployment Credentials
2. Enter in a new password and save (please ignore the validation error after saving)
3. After the update succeeds, try creating a new App Service Plan, or Web App with a new App Service Plan.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried creating new service plan, recheck properly the IAM and waited for few hours, and the issue was resolved automatically.